# On validating the Azure Devops git configuration in the Azure portal for Azure Data Factory service getting an error prompt

Tags: azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

I had used Terraform to configure Azure git in Azure Data Factory but after post deployment on Validating the connection I am getting a prompt with an error. I have attached the screenshot below.

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "testadfrg"
  location = "West Europe"
}
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "df" {
  name                   = "testadfadf"
  location               = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  public_network_enabled = "true"

  vsts_configuration {
    account_name    = "organizationaz440"
    branch_name     = "Development"
    project_name    = "TestProject"
    repository_name = "DataOps"
    root_folder     = "/ADF"
    tenant_id       = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: if you open the git config part you can see your variables there

Answer (score 0):

It seems your user account which is trying to open ADF studio to validate changes doesn't have access on Git Repo. Kindly work with Git repo admins  with error details. They should be able to give you relevant permissions.